# Missing Gulpfile Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

```
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp:11
  throw new Error("Missing Gulpfile");
        ^
Error: Missing Gulpfile
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp:11:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

I'm getting this error when I try to do gulp -v.

node -v(0.10.25) works fine and so does npm -v(1.3.24).

I've followed the tutorial from their github but no succes. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#getting-started

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Did you create a `Gulpfile`? It is step 3 in your tutorial.

Comment: Also, it's `gulpfile.js` — all lowercase!

Comment: I have a gulpfile and checked it by even copy pasting some others. My filename is all lowercase, the "Gulpfile" error has nothing to do with my actual filename.

Comment: Can you try reinstalling the global and local versions of gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem on Ubuntu 12.04.

First, check what version of gulp you have installed in your project - for some mysterious reason my package.json had an older version which it kept installing, this old version required a file called "Gulpfile.js".

Also, trying running the command more verbosely:

/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --gulpfile /path/to/your/gulpfile.js

There seems to be an issue with the symbolic link of /usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js to /usr/bin/gulp. gulp.js has some relative requirements (ie. line 10 https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/bin/gulp.js) which are not being resolved properly when run from the CLI.

I ran "npm cache clean" a few times while troubleshooting this, which clears out bad installs - I don't know if it helped but might be worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the global copy of gulp.  (`npm update --global`)  If that doesn't resolve it, post a bug on https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem also on Ubuntu 12.04. In my case the cause of the problem was an old gulp copy I had installed in a nodejs version 0.6.x. Then I uninstalled nodejs to install a newer version (v0.10.28), it seems all the modules are removed from /usr/lib/node_modules, but the executables are not removed.

So when I installed again gulp, the executable was from a previous version and I was having your problem. What I did to fix the problem was:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g gulp

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/gulp

sudo npm install -g gulp
```

Now it should work properly

Comment: Going to try this out when I get home.